# PHP upload image and file to a specified folder

Tags: php

Hi all i need to create a form to upload two files to a specified folder that is created by the selection of a select and an input on the same page.

So the form must have:
input type="text"
select
upload image on the folder "select_value/input_value/random_name_image.jpg"
upload file on the folder "select_value/input_value/random_name_file.txt"

someone can help me to create this form?
thanks a lot

Comment: i don't know how to do this form. How to upload the files to the specified folder

Comment: Related: [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) in the PHP manual - it's a bit dry, but has a full working example

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
// Build destination path from the text input and select
$dest = ...;

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "{$dest}/{$_FILES['image']['name']}")) {
  echo('Error with image');
  die();
}
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "{$dest}/{$_FILES['file']['name']}")) {
  echo('Error with image');
  die();
}
```

Check out [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) for more information. Make sure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` specified (major waste of time if you forget that).